# Moving a JTextArea around a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am trying to move a JTextArea by clicking and dragging. I have the basic concept down but for some reason, when I drag it, it is showing up along the path I drag. It is easiest to explain by showing you:

[image]

I'm not sure what is wrong because I'm not creating a new JTextArea on a Mouse Drag, I am using: `component.setLocation(x, y);`

Why is this happening?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class Editor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Window();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 700);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Window extends JFrame {
    MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Window() {
        addMenus();
    }

    public void addMenus() {

        getContentPane().add(myPanel);

        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyPanel() {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Some text\nSome other text");
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        add(textArea);
        DragListener drag = new DragListener();
        textArea.addMouseListener(drag);
        textArea.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    }

    public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
        Point location;
        MouseEvent pressed;

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            pressed = me;
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            Component component = me.getComponent();
            location = component.getLocation(location);
            int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
            int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
            component.setLocation(x, y);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Painting in Swing is made up a chain of (complex) method calls.  If you choose to break this chain, the you had better be ready to take over the work that this methods do...

The `Graphics` context is a shared resource, that is, the same `Graphics` context will be passed to each component involved in a given paint cycle.  It is the responsibility of each component to first clear the `Graphics` context before performing any custom painting

You've overriden `paintComponent`...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
}
```

but you have failed to honour it's responsibilities, one of which is to clear the `Graphics` context before painting.

If you intend to do some custom painting, I would highly recommend calling `super.paintComponent` first...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

or, if you have no intention of performing custom painting, remove the method altogether.

Take a look at

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

for more details

You should also have a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and make sure you are intialising your UIs within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: Ah, I actually knew this! I am painting but I removed the painting code to make the example simpler, but forgot to take away the override of paintComponent. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am having trouble adding these JTextArea's dynamically. Check out this question if you have a chance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705798/dynamically-adding-a-jtextarea-to-jpanel-not-working thanks