# Dynamically Adding a JTextArea to Jpanel not working

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

So, on the click of a JMenu button, I want to dynamically add a JTextArea to my JPanel. For some reason, it isn't showing up when it is expected to. I am using this code to add it:

```
drag = new DragListener();
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Some text\nSome other text");
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
add(textArea);
textArea.addMouseListener(drag);
textArea.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
```

And I know this code works when I do it when the JPanel class is initialized, like this:

```
public MyPanel() {
    drag = new DragListener();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Some text\nSome other text");
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    add(textArea);
    textArea.addMouseListener(drag);
    textArea.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
}
```

But when I add it dynamically using another method, it isn't adding. Why is this

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class Editor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Window();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 700);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Window extends JFrame {
    MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Window() {
        addMenus();
    }

    public void addMenus() {

        getContentPane().add(myPanel);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenuItem addBox = new JMenuItem("Add Menu");
        addBox.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        addBox.setToolTipText("Exit application");
        addBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                myPanel.addBox();
            }
        });

        menubar.add(addBox);
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    DragListener drag;

    public MyPanel() {
        drag = new DragListener();
        drag = new DragListener();
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Some text\nSome other text");
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        add(textArea);
        textArea.addMouseListener(drag);
        textArea.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
    }

    public void addBox() {
        drag = new DragListener();
        JTextArea textArea2 = new JTextArea("Some text\nSome other text");
        textArea2.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        add(textArea2);
        textArea2.addMouseListener(drag);
        textArea2.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
        repaint();
        revalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
        Point location;
        MouseEvent pressed;

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            pressed = me;
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
            Component component = me.getComponent();
            location = component.getLocation(location);
            int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
            int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
            component.setLocation(x, y);
        }
    }

}
```

**Update**

Now that I have solved this problem, I have ran into another.

When I add a new JTextArea to the Panel, it is resetting all of the other JTextArea's positions on the panel. Ideas?

[image]

Comment: *"on the click of a JMenu button, I want to dynamically add a JTextArea to my JPanel."*  Use a `CardLayout` instead..  It is easy and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add...

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

to the end of your `addBox` method, this will encourage the layout manager to update the container the repaint manager to repaint the component

Also, please don't use `JMenuBar` and `JMenuItem`s this way, it is counter intuitive to users, instead, use a `JToolBar` and `JButton`

See [How to Use Tool Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for more details

Dragging the `JTextArea` in this manner is also...annoying.  How does the user highlight the text now?

Take a look at [Dragging-and-dropping to move a JTextArea around on JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599600/dragging-and-dropping-to-move-a-jtextarea-around-on-jpanel/26600026#26600026) for another idea

Comment: Thanks. I tried using repaint() but I was unaware of using revalidate(). Also, will look into JToolBar!

Comment: I have updated the question with yet another problem I've run into. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Does it have anything to do with revalidate() ?

Comment: Actually, yes, the panel is under the control of a layout manager, calling `revalidate` will cause the layout manager to re-evaluate the position and size of the components under it's control

Comment: Anyway to fix this? Can you override revaildate by chance? The only way I can think is to keep track of each JTextArea's coordinates and then set them on revalidate. Not sure if there is an easier way, though

Comment: Sorry, no experience with layout managers. I'll check them out. Will I need a layout manager for each JTextArea or one for the whole JPanel?

Comment: For an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819669/absolute-positioning-graphic-jpanel-inside-jframe-blocked-by-blank-sections/11822601#11822601).  You will only need a single layout manager for the panel

Comment: Thanks, will check out your answer.